# Read Level II Ridge Radar Data in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

This is a little strange for me as I never post these questions. In many years of learning a few different languages this is the first time I have not been able to find the answers I am looking for.

I have looked everywhere for a Python module that can open and read level II radar data files. I have found a few that work in python 2.7, but nothing at all that works in python 3. Py-ART won't work in 3, wradlib won't work in 3, nbviewer won't work in 3. So I have been looking everywhere for an explanation on how to open the level II data files and convert them into something useful in Python. I am very surprised at how little documentation there is out there on even what kind of files these are, let alone how to open them and parse information from them. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on opening these files in Python 3, or to be pointed in the direction of a module that can do this in Python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Woah, whats up with the - votes?

Comment: I'm imagining because of the rules that state: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Right and I asked for help with someone that knows some python tools for opening and reading these files after explaining that off site resources didn't help me.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I think your question is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Py-ART now works in Python 3. You should be good to go now

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.